# Power series representation of a function

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am trying to find a power series representation of

$$ \frac{1-x}{1+x} $$

My textbook does it by adding one and subtracting one on the numerator. I understand this method but was wondering if anyone could give me some input on doing it by the following method:

$$(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}x^{n} $$

where the series is just the geometric series replaced by  $-x$.

After multiplying out I get stuck here:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}x^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}x^{n+1} $$

I'm not sure how I could progress or if this method is actually doable, any input would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: @Reveillark Did you not read all the way through the problem?

Comment: Yes! I understand there are other ways to do it much like the one done in my textbook, I was just hoping to get some input on the method I stated above and whether it's valid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-index:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n-1$$

> $$=-1+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n$$

Comment: You haven't done the reindexing right: the constant term should be $1$ not $2$.

Comment: This looks like just the answer I need! I'm just a bit confused on the second step and how you got the -x at the end?

Comment: @RobArthan I can't find what I did wrong.  Could you explain?

Comment: @melm I took the $n=0$ term out of the second original sum.

Comment: Doesn't it look like this: $(1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \ldots) - (x - x^2 + x^ 3 - \ldots) = 1 - 2x + 2x^2 - 2x^ 3 + \ldots$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I see! Thank you very much I understand now

Comment: @melm Sorry, RobArthan caught a mistake.  Indeed, I think looking at his comment may do you better.  Now, I added one to the second original sum and then re-indexed everything to look better, and to preserve equality, I subtracted one as well.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt could I ask why you added 1 to the second original sum? Is that one of the terms of the original sum? I was just a bit confused as the original sum has x to the power of (n+1) so I'm not sure where the 1 came from. Thanks!

Comment: @melm Note:$$1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}=(-1)^{-1+1}x^{-1+1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dots$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt We've only just learned this, I didn't know I could do that haha thank you!

Comment: @melm :D Well, hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer do the following
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-x}{1+x}&=-1+\frac{2}{1+x}\\
&=-1+2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=\left[-1+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n\right]+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=\left[-1+(1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots)\right]+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=(-x+x^2-x^3+\dots)+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=-x(1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots)+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=-x\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=(-x+1)\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nx^n.
&
\end{align}
$$